# Can I tell GRUB to boot into a Windows OS that exists as a virtual disk on a Linux system?

Tags: windows, linux, grub, bootloader, grub2

I know that GRUB (and GRUB2) can chainload a Windows OS if you specify the hdd that it is contained on.
Is it possible to tell GRUB (or GRUB2) to boot into a dd image-file of a Windows OS that is located on a Linux filesystem? Alternatively, is it possible to use some other bootloader to accomplish this?

I'm not trying to run a VM, but rather run the system as if it were the main installed OS, with little overhead. I've seen something sort of like this done from Android to Linux using chroot, but Windows itself doesn't support chroot or boot in the same way as a Linux system.

Comment: I have, since asking this question, found this to be impossible - Grub's filesystem access goes away when it starts the OS, so the system can't do anything. Even if you set it up and tell grub to do it, it just hangs after you select the entry.

Answer (score 0):

With some exceptions it is possible for Vista and up Windows... the virtual file must not be a dd image, instead it must be a .VHD/.VHDX one.

That file must be fixed size (if dynamic it will be expanded to max on first boot) and not fragmented, stored on a NTFS partition without compression and without any encryption (no BitLocker, etc).

Windows (from Vista) have a native way to boot Windows system from inside .VHD/.VHDX file (if search on M$ will see only for PRO/Enterprise, but some 3rd party tools allow on home versions also).

Also there is a howto for WinXP.

I still had not tried it, but there is out there a lot info... search bot Booting Windows from a .vhd file.

Warning, you will need a NTFS partition for a BCD on wich you configure that boot from VHD.

Sorry i can not be of more help.

Then Grub2 can chainload that bcd boot.. but remember the vhd/vhdx file must be on a NTFS plain (no compress / no encrypted) partition.

FAT32 can not have files of size >=4GiB. Ext# (and other linux filesystems, etc) can not be used to hold the file (windows must know partition filesystem at boot, so only FAT/FAT12/FAT16/FAT32/exFAT/NTFS).

Why an exFAT can not be used? No idea, maybe it can be used to hold... by i allways see NTFS as a must!